# Ошибка линковки libtcc

Tags: c, include

Вознкла надобнось импортировать Tiny C Compiller в C проект.
Нашел вот такой тестовый код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libtcc.h>

void compileAndRun(const char* sourceCode) {
    TCCState *tcc = tcc_new();
    if (!tcc) {
        printf("Error: Could not create TCC instance.\n");
        return;
    }

    tcc_add_include_path(tcc, "C:\\tcc\\libtcc");

    if (tcc_compile_string(tcc, sourceCode) == -1) {
        printf("Error: Compilation failed.\n");
        tcc_delete(tcc);
        return;
    }

    if (tcc_relocate(tcc, TCC_RELOCATE_AUTO) < 0) {
        printf("Error: Linking failed.\n");
        tcc_delete(tcc);
        return;
    }

    int (*mainFunc)(void) = (int (*)(void))tcc_get_symbol(tcc, "main");
    if (!mainFunc) {
        printf("Error: Failed to find 'main' function.\n");
        tcc_delete(tcc);
        return;
    }

    int ret = mainFunc();

    tcc_delete(tcc);

    printf("Program returned: %d\n", ret);
}

int main() {
    const char* sourceCode = 
        "#include <stdio.h>\n"
        "int main() {\n"
        "    printf(\"Hello World!\\n\");\n"
        "    return 0;\n"
        "}\n";

    compileAndRun(sourceCode);

    return 0;
}
```

Однако нормально импортировать libtcc.h не смог, установил TCC, и пробовал скомпилировать проект с помощью: `gcc -o main main.c compile.c -I"C:\tcc\include" -L"C:\tcc\lib" -ltcc`,
получаю ошибку:

```
In file included from C:\tcc\include/stdio.h:9,
                 from main.c:1:
C:\tcc\include/_mingw.h:39: warning: "__fastcall" redefined
   39 | #define __fastcall __attribute__((fastcall))
      |
<built-in>: note: this is the location of the previous definition
C:\tcc\include/_mingw.h:72: warning: "__stdcall" redefined
   72 | #define __stdcall
      |
<built-in>: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from main.c:2:
C:\tcc\include/stdlib.h:139:3: error: duplicate 'extern'
  139 |   _CRTIMP extern int *__cdecl _errno(void);
      |   ^~~~~~~
main.c:3:10: fatal error: libtcc.h: No such file or directory
    3 | #include <libtcc.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Извините если вопрос слишком тупой, однако нигде в интернете не удалось найти информацию как правильно импортировать libtcc.h

я нашёл файл libtcc.h в tcc/libtcc однако проблему это не решило
изменил команду на такую: `gcc -o main main.c -I"C:\tcc\libtcc" -L"C:\tcc\lib" -ltcc`
Теперь получаю ошибку:

```
c:/users/lubim/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ltcc
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: `libtcc.h` нельзя импортировать, это заголовочный файл. `cannot find -ltcc` означает, что линкер не  может найти соотв. библиотеку. Так что сначала вам следует разобраться, где именно у вас находится та библиотека, которую вы собираетесь линковать. Заметьте, если команды выполняются в баше-подобном интерпретаторе команд, то `\\` там служит экранирующим символом. Кроме того, у tcc сложная система зависимостей. Ему для работы нужны libgcc, заголовочные файлы стандартной библиотеки и т.п.

Answer (score -1):

### Ошибка

Ошибка `"cannot find -ltcc"` возникает потому, что компилятор не может найти библиотеку `libtcc`. Попробуйте убедиться, что путь к папке с библиотеками `TCC` указан правильно. Если вы используете `Windows`, убедитесь, что вы добавили путь к папке с библиотеками `TCC` в переменную среды `PATH`.

---

### Решение

Если проблема сохраняется, попробуйте скомпилировать и установить `TCC` с поддержкой `libtcc` с помощью исходных кодов. Для этого загрузите исходные коды `TCC` с официального сайта, распакуйте архив и выполните следующие команды:

```
./configure --enable-libtcc
make
sudo make install
```

Замените `"sudo"` на команду, которая используется для выполнения команд от имени администратора на вашей системе. После установки `TCC` с поддержкой `libtcc` попробуйте скомпилировать вашу программу снова.

Comment: Я изменил свой вопрос, пересмотрите пожалуйста